# Increasing the width of type "h" R plot

Tags: r, plot

If I run this simple code:

```
x <- c(1:10)
y <- c(1:10)
plot(x,y,type="h")
```

the result contains very thin histogram lines.

[image: my plot]

Is there a way to make these lines thicker (other than using the hist() function itself)? They do not necessarily have to look like bars, just be a little thicker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
plot(x,y,type="h", lwd = 4)
```

Comment: Add `lend=1` to give squared-off line caps, which look more like bars. Otherwise, the line caps will be rounded, and the rounded part will actually protrude above the top value and below zero. In addition, probably best to add `ylim=c(0,10)` so that the "bars" go down to zero. For example: `plot(x,y,type="h", lwd=20, lend=1, ylim=c(0,10)); lines(x,y, type="h", col="grey60", lwd=10)`.

Comment: @eipi10 Brilliant comment