# Bar Plot with 2 y axes and same x axis in R language

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot a bar graph with two different y axes and same x axis.

For some reason, I am not able to plot using barplot in R. I tried the same with plot function. But can not come close to what I wanted.

Here is the data:

```
x,y1,y2
1,130,1525157
2,84,1070393
3,140,1263374
4,346,2620949
5,354,2939962
6,300,3303101
7,127,1647361
8,69,1168261
9,44,7447573
10,38,12804778
11,12,570379
12,22,3100184
13,7,236046
14,23,2322048
```

The code is used to try is below:

```
options(scipen=10000000)
bargraph_test <- read.csv(file="data_test.csv",head=TRUE,sep=",")
attach(bargraph_test)
plot(x = x, y = y1, col = "blue", type = "h", xlab = "x", ylab = "y1", main = "")
par(new = T)
plot(x = x, y = y1, col = "green", type = "h", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "")
axis(4)
mtext("y2", side = 4, line = 3)
```

I am attaching the screenshot here of the output I get.

[image]

I need to display these lines as bar patterns.

Can someone help me with this situation.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: 2 different y-axis are discussed in detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/plot-with-2-y-axes-one-y-axis-on-the-left-and-another-y-axis-on-the-right

Answer (score 2):

Using `highcharter` you can add as many Y-axis you want. Simply add another entry in `hc_yAxis_multiples` & `hc_add_series`.

```r
library(highcharter)

highchart() %>% 
  hc_yAxis_multiples(
    list(lineWidth = 3, lineColor='blue', title=list(text="y1")),
    list(lineWidth = 3, lineColor="green", title=list(text="y2"))
  ) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = df$y1, color='blue', type = "column") %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = df$y2, color='green', type = "column", yAxis = 1) %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = df$x, title = list(text = "x"))
```

**Output Plot:**
[image: Output plot]

```
#sample data
> dput(df)
structure(list(x = 1:14, y1 = c(130L, 84L, 140L, 346L, 354L, 
300L, 127L, 69L, 44L, 38L, 12L, 22L, 7L, 23L), y2 = c(1525157L, 
1070393L, 1263374L, 2620949L, 2939962L, 3303101L, 1647361L, 1168261L, 
7447573L, 12804778L, 570379L, 3100184L, 236046L, 2322048L)), .Names = c("x", 
"y1", "y2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L))
```

Answer (score 1):

As the last sentences of the question indicates, the actual question is "How do I get wider bars/lines?". I answer to that question and not to the question in the questions title.

You can use the parameter `lwd` to make the lines thicker. To get nice ends of the bars/lines: please see this [answer to 'Increasing the width of type “h” R plot'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38002421/4612235) and use `lend=1`.

```
# data
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14)
y1 <- c(130,84,140,346,354,300,127,69,44,38,12,22,7,23)
y2 <- c(1525157,1070393,1263374,2620949,2939962,3303101,1647361,1168261,7447573,12804778,570379,3100184,236046,2322048)

# what-ever ...
options(scipen=10000000)

# first set of bars
plot(x = x-0.1, y = y1, col = "blue", type = "h", xlab = "x", ylab = "y1", main = "", xlim = range(x), lwd = 4, lend = 1)
# new:
#  xlim = range(x) :: we need it so that the x-axis is not shifted
#  lwd = 4         :: thicker lines
#  lend = 1        :: flat line ends
#  please note 'x-0.1'

# add second set of bars
par(new = T)
plot(x = x + 0.1, y = y2, col = "green", type = "h", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "", xlim = range(x), lwd = 4, lend=1)

# second y-axis
axis(4)
mtext("y2", side = 4, line = 3)
```