# R - Frequency histogram from sampling: efficiency and more

Tags: r, performance, histogram

I'm a university student, beginning to explore R for an exam.
Sorry for the vague title, as I have many questions related to this post.

I've run into the problem of sampling a population of people who are either Male (M) or Female (F). I wished to define a function that could take the number of Males and Females in this population, then create `sample.number` samples of size `sample.size` and return a data frame containing the sample proportions of females over the total size of the sample, with related frequencies.

I'm positive there is a simple and well-optimized way to do this, but I've written a small function that (barely) works:

```
senators <- function(Fem = 13, 
                 Mal = 87, 
                 sample.size = 10, 
                 sample.number = 100){

pop <- c(rep("F", Fem), rep("M", Mal)) # I create the population base

popsa <- list(NA)           # I make some empty variables used later
popsa.factor <- list(NA)    # Not sure if this passage is even needed...
popsa.proportion <- list(NA)
```

Here comes a `for` loop. I've read that `for` loops are really inefficient way to do this. Is there a better way?

```
for(i in 1:sample.number){
  popsa[[i]] <- sample(pop, sample.size, replace = TRUE)
  popsa.factor[[i]] <- table(factor(popsa[[i]], levels = c("M", "F")))
  popsa.proportion[[i]] <- popsa.factor[[i]][2]/sample.size
  }
```

I start by assigning each element of the list `popsa` with a sample, then I use `popsa` to create a table from each sample, and store it in `popsa.factor`. Then I calculate the proportions of females over the total and store it in `popsa.proportion`. This `for` loop seems super messy to me, and is really slow to process lots of samples. Is there a better, more efficient way to do what I've done here?

```
popsa.unlisted <- unlist(popsa.proportion)
popsa.frequency <- table(popsa.unlisted)

popsa.frame <- data.frame(Level = as.numeric(names(popsa.frequency)), 
                          Freq =  as.numeric(popsa.frequency))
return(popsa.frame)
} # This closes the function call
```

I then unlist `popsa.proportion` to get every proportion in a vector, and table those values to get the frequencies, storing them into `popsa.frequency`. Now I try to turn the factor `popsa.frequency` into a data frame, by cheating and converting the names of `popsa.frequency` as numeric and storing them as the first column of the data frame. The function then returns `popsa.frame`, as I wanted.

`popsa.frame`, though, still carries over the factor properties of `popsa.frequency` in its first column (`Level`). How can I change this? Should I?

Since these are frequencies of a sample distribution, I'd like to create an histogram from this dataframe, although `hist()` only accepts numeric vectors, so `popsa.frame` isn't a valid object. `plot(popsa.frame)` returns more or less what I want, though. How can I create such an histogram?

Edit: Following the marked answer below, I've also come up on how to simply convert the data frame the function creates into an object that `hist()` can actually use to create a frequency histogram (although using a barplot yields more or less the same graph, and possibly be a more statistically correct way to show such a result):

```
result <- senators(Fem=13,Mal=87,sample.size=50,sample.number=10000)

raw <- sapply(1:length(result$Level), function(x){
  rep(result$Level, result$Freq)
})

hist(raw)
```

Comment: So, you want to do histograms for each column of you `data.frame`?

Comment: Not exactly, I wish to create a single histogram, where in the "y" axis are the frequencies, and in the "x" axis are the proportion values. @patL
Something like [This](https://i.imgur.com/pgSRKX9.png), but with the columns of an histogram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The creation of the lists and the for loop has some performance bottlenecks.  I was able to use `sapply` to remove the `for loop` and some of the temporary variables.

I am still returning the data fame and another option would return the vector answer just pass the result to the histogram plotting function for your final plot.

```
senators <- function(Fem = 13, 
                     Mal = 87, 
                     sample.size = 10, 
                     sample.number = 100){

  pop <- c(rep("F", Fem), rep("M", Mal)) # I create the population base

  answer<-sapply(1:sample.number, function(x){popsa <- sample(pop, sample.size, replace = TRUE);
                                            length(popsa[popsa=="F"])/sample.size})

popsa.frequency <- table(answer)

popsa.frame <- data.frame(Level = as.numeric(names(popsa.frequency)), 
                          Freq =  as.numeric(popsa.frequency))
return(popsa.frame)
} 

senators()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function has some default values that leads to the creation of a `data.frame` by just doing `senators()`.

Following your data I would do:

```
df <- senators() # using default values
plot(df, type="h", lwd = 5, lend=1) # type changes your plot type while lwd changes line sizes, while lend would give squared aspect yo your bars.
```

Take a look at `?plot` to see the types of plots you can do. Also, you can see how change parameters by doing `?par`.

P.S.: look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38002360/increasing-the-width-of-type-h-r-plot) for line width details.